# return database item only if files exist in directory with codeigniter php

Tags: php, codeigniter, model, directory

I'm currently populating a table of information from my database. However, the only information that is returned are rows where the "available" field is set to 1. i.e if it is set to 0 the database will not return that row.

I also have a directory of files which will typically have 5 files per table item all with a naming convention similar to:

first_1234.txt
second_1234.txt
third_1234.txt
fourth_1234.txt
fifth_1234.txt

What I need to do is take the information from this table, and somehow link it to the files in my directory. the "1234" section of the files will match  a column in my table. 
If the files are available in the directory I want to show it in the table, other than that I want to hide it. I'm sorry if I haven't explained this well! But does anyone have any ideas how I'd do this? 
I'm using the code igniter framework for this also.

I know I can scan the directory and return the items using:

```
    $dir    = 'myfolder';
    $files1 = scandir($dir);
    print_r($files1);
```

But how do I link them to what my database is returning?

Thanks!

UPDATE:
I am printing my table using the following code:

```
            <?php echo validation_errors();?>
   <?php if (is_array($files)) {?>
        <?php foreach($files as $file){?>

            <tr>
                <td><?php echo $file->ID;?></td>
                <td><?php echo $file->name;?></td>
                <td><?php echo $file->filename;?></td>
            </tr>

        <?php }}}?>
</table>
```

Comment: In your condition call this function `scandir('dir_name')` with directory name

Comment: use PHP is_file( $file )?

Comment: @RichardMauritz how would I go about working it into my table though? Ive updated my code to show how I'm printing my table but I don't know how to tie everything together.. I tried putting the is_file($file) below the foreach statement but its crashing it..

Comment: Yes, you need the path to your file. so make it is_file($pathtofile);
Is there a row in your database which contains the path? If so whats the table name, else give me the path where files are located. I than can give you a good awnser